# How can i change the location of scrollBar of ListView in Qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have created a ListView with a scrollBar. Like this

[image]

Here is my code,

```
ListView {
    id: listView;
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
        id: bar
        //x :100 doesn't work
        active: true

      }
    }
```

In my case, i want to reset the location of the scrollbar. For example,move the scrollbar to the right by 5 pixels more. I tried to **set "x:"** , but didn't work. How can i solve my problem.

Comment: if you are going to move the scrollbar to the right it will come out of the window,

Comment: How about move it to the left, i just want know how to change the location of scrollbar in listview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to establish that property a moment after loading the `ScrollBar` since the `ListView` sets it to the default position.

```
ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
    id: sb
    active: true
    Component.onCompleted: x = 100
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can move the `ScrollBar` outside of the `ListView` and reference it inside the `ListView` with its `id`:

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    ScrollBar.vertical: bar
}

ScrollBar {
    id: bar
    active: true
    anchors {
        left: listView.left
        top: listView.top
        bottom: listView.bottom
        leftMargin: 100
    }
}
```